# Is there a way to down cast a struct to its derived one in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, downcast

Here is my situation:

```
struct A {
    int numberAllChildStructsUse;
}

struct B : A {
    std::string strUniqueToB;
}

struct C : A {
    std::string strUniqueToC;
}
```

(in some source file)

```
B b = thisFunctionReturnsBOrCStructsAsTypeA(int idThatGuaranteesItIsTypeBNotC);
```

`Error: no suitable user-defined conversion from A to B exists` when I try that above line. What is the best way to get this to work? Struct A represents the commonalities that all Bs, Cs share. The member vars inside of B and C are unique to each other. That function returns A type structs, but I know that they are actually in fact either Bs or Cs, and can tell based off of the parameter I supply.

Comment: dynamic_cast is used to cast between objects which are part of the same hierarchy
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: If you know at the callsite what type the function will return, you could perhaps make it into two separate functions. `thisFunctionReturnsB` and `thisFunctionReturnsC`.

Comment: I do have those two functions as well, but I wanted for simplicities sake to be able to have one function that finds all the structs (there are like 20). So I wouldn't have to write 20 different thisFunctionReturns_ funcs

Comment: Doesn't seem to be simpler, does it?

Comment: If this issue never cropped up and I was in C# or something I could just have done "B b = returnsAnyStruct() as B" :P then it would have been simple

Comment: You still need to return a pointer or reference instead of a value, since currently you'll be slicing out just the base-class subobject.

Comment: @dmscs In C#, those classes would have all been heap-allocated and would have associated vtables. This is all possible to do in C++ too, but they are not done by default because they have significant overhead. If you make your classes polymorphic and return a `unique_ptr<A>` or `shared_ptr<A>` from your function, it will be just as simple as it is in C#. That is not idiomatic C++ way of doing things though. If you add more details about what exactly you are trying to solve, we can show you better ways to do that in C++.

Comment: It seems that dynamic casting is working for me. I tried unique/shared pointers, but I got an error which I forget now what it was. The function I mentioned in the body now returns the address of whatever struct it finds. With the address, I can make a dynamic_cast to a B* or C* etc. 

Really, I just have a ton of structs (like 20 different types) and wanted a single function that gets all of them (in a std::map) and finds the one I am looking for. I know at the callsite what type the result should be based off the supplied ID parameter so I think I can get away with dynamic casting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic_cast` for this, but only if the class hierarchy is *polymorphic*.

To achieve the latter, write

```
struct A {
    int numberAllChildStructsUse;
    virtual ~A() = default;
};
```

reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast

Comment: It is worth mentioning that more often than not `dynamic_cast` tends to point to flaws in design. Ideally, when IS-A principle is properly observed, this cast is not required.

Comment: Thank you. Why is it important that its polymorphic?

Comment: @dmscs:If it's not polymorphic then `dynamic_cast` doesn't work. If you want a polymorphic type then you probably also want a virtual destructor. The technique I give kills both these birds with one stone.

Answer (score 3):

If your function returns by value, slicing possibly happens and you can't get a `B`.

If your function returns a reference or a pointer, you have 2 options:

1. If you are absolutely certain that the dynamic type is a pointer/reference to `B`, you can use `static_cast`. It has zero overhead, but if you get the type wrong you get UB.
2. If you are not sure if the dynamic type is a pointer/reference to `B`, and your type is polymorphic (has a virtual function), then you can use `dynamic_cast`. It will report the error so you can handle the failure case at the cost of [some overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778220/10147399). In my experience, `dynamic_cast` is often a sign of poor design, so be careful not to obfuscate stuff.